# SQL - Select records not present in another table (3 table relation)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables:

```
Table_Cars
-id_car
-description

Table_CarDocuments
-id_car
-id_documentType
-path_to_document

Table_DocumentTypes
-id_documentType
-description
```

I want to select all cars that do **NOT** have documents on the table Table_CarDocuments with 4 specific id_documentType.

Something like this:

```
Car1 | TaxDocument
Car1 | KeyDocument
Car2 | TaxDocument
```

With this i know that i'm missing 2 documents of car1 and 1 document of car2.

Comment: Sample data and desired results help.  Do you want all four documents missing?  Or do you want if any of the four are missing?

Comment: Want to get 1 line for each document missing for each car

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for missing car documents. So cross join cars and document types and look for combinations NOT IN the car douments table.

```
select c.description as car, dt.description as doctype
from table_cars c
cross join table_documenttypes dt
where (c.id_car, dt.id_documenttype) not in
(
  select cd.id_car, cd.id_documenttype
  from table_cardocuments cd
);
```

UPDATE: It shows that SQL Server's IN clause is very limited and not capable of dealing with value lists. But a NOT IN clause can easily be replaced by NOT EXISTS:

```
select c.description as car, dt.description as doctype
from table_cars c
cross join table_documenttypes dt
where not exists
(
  select *
  from table_cardocuments cd
  where cd.id_car = c.id_car
  and cd.id_documenttype = dt.id_documenttype
);
```

UPDATE: As you are only interested in particular id_documenttype (for which you'd have to add `and dt.id_documenttype in (1, 2, 3, 4)` to the query), you can generate records for them on-the-fly instead of having to read the table_documenttypes.

In order to do that replace

```
cross join table_documenttypes dt
```

with

```
cross join (values (1), (2), (3), (4)) as dt(id_documentType)
```

Comment: Not working in MS SQL. Did it like this:

select c.description as car, dt.description as doctype
from table_cars c
cross join table_documenttypes dt
where dt.id no in (
(
  select cd.id_documentType
  from table_cardocuments cd
  where cd.idcar = c.id AND cd.id_doctype = dt.id
)
AND dt.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: What does "not working" mean? An error? Too many records? Too few? As to the syntax: There is one parenthesis too many after IN. And you wrote `NO IN` instead of `NOT IN`.

Comment: And your IN clause is obfuscated. An IN clause should be non-correlated, but you refer to dt values inside the subquery. Why did you change it? Is SQL Server not able to deal with tuples? Maybe. Then make this a NOT EXISTS. I'll edit my answer right away.

Comment: I've just looked it up; `(column list) [NOT] IN (...)` seems not to be supported in SQL Server (which I consider a pity, as I think this feature makes queries very readable). So one has to use `[NOT] EXISTS` instead when dealing with more than one value in SQL Server. Here is the documentation on the IN clause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: I think MS SQL can't handle this: 'where (c.id_car, dt.id_documenttype)'

Comment: Yep, that's what I am saying. Unlike other DBMS SQL Server doesn't support column lists with the IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query below to get the result:

```
SELECT
    c.description,
    dt.description
FROM
    Table_Cars c
    JOIN Table_CarDocuments cd ON c.id_car = cd.id_car
    JOIN Table_DocumentTypes dt ON cd.id_documentType = dt.id_documentType
WHERE
    dt.id_documentType NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4) --replace with your document type id
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a complicated query.  The idea is to generate all combinations of cars and the four documents that you want (using `cross join`).  Then use `left join` to determine if the document actually exists:

```
select c.id_car, dd.doctype
from cars c cross join
     (select 'doc1' as doctype union all
      select 'doc2' union all
      select 'doc3' union all
      select 'doc4'
     ) dd left join
     CarDocuments cd
     on c.id_car = cd.id_car left join
     Documents d
     on cd.id_document_type = d.id_document_type and d.doctype = dd.doctype
where dd.id_document_type is null;
```

Finally, the `where` clause finds the car/doctype pairs that are not present in the data.

Comment: When a car has already one of the documents (it doesn't have the 3 other), it doesn't show up in the results

Comment: @DiogoAlmeida . . . That is very strange.  This should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Thorsten Kettner help

```
select c.description as car, dt.description as doctype
from table_cars c
cross join table_documenttypes dt
where dt.id no in (
(
  select cd.id_documentType
  from table_cardocuments cd
  where cd.idcar = c.id AND cd.id_doctype = dt.id
)
AND dt.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```